# Passing array arguments by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, pass-by-reference

I came across a function with this signature.

```
void foo(char (&x)[5])
{
}
```

This is the syntax for passing a fixed size char array by reference.

The fact that it requires parentheses around `&x` strikes me as unusual.

It is probably part of the C++03 standard.

What is this form called and can anyone point out a reference to the standard?

c++decl is not a friend yet:

```
$ c++decl 
Type `help' or `?' for help
c++decl> explain void foo(char (&x)[5])
syntax error
```

Comment: I can't point to the standard, but I believe it's because `char& x[5]` is an array of 5 character references, not a reference to a character array of length 5.

Comment: 8.3.2 References "There shall be no references to references, no arrays of references, and no pointers to references."

Comment: Wasn't it a really great call to use punctuation for such features.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is nothing unusual or new about the syntax. You see it all the time in C with pointers. `[]` has higher precedence than `&`, so you need to put it in parentheses if you want to declare a reference to an array. The same thing happens with `*` (which has the same precedence as `&`): For example, to declare a pointer to an array of 5 chars in C, you would do `char (*x)[5];`. Similarly, a pointer to a function that takes and returns an int would be `int (*x)(int);` (`()` has same precedence as `[]`). The story is the same with references, except that references are only on C++ and there are some restrictions to what types can be formed from references.

Comment: +1 For explaining the requirement of the parentheses. Where are the restrictions on forming types from references documented?

Comment: @Eddy Pronk: I was referring to the statement you cited in your comment to your question above

Answer (score 11):

There's nothing to explain, this is simply how the parsing rules for declarations work in C++:

```
char  & x[5] // declare x as array 5 of reference to char (not valid C++!)
char (&x)[5] // declare x as reference to array 5 of char
```

**Caution:** The first version is not valid C++, though, since you cannot have arrays of references. This is merely an explanation of the declaration syntax. (Sorry about taking so long to get this right, and thanks to the helpful comments!)

You're allowed to wrap the type identifier in arbitray levels of parentheses if you like, so you can also say `char &(x)[5]` (first case) or `char (((&x)))[5]` (second case).

Comment: Which compiler accepts the first form? gcc 4.4.5 doesn't: error: declaration of ‘x’ as array of references

Comment: Except, of course, that the first isn't legal C++, since you're not allowed to have arrays of references.

Comment: It seems you're required to wrap at least one level of parentheses.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Not as free-standing declarations, but as function argument declarations! Good point :-)

Comment: Compare `void (*funcptr)(int)` to declare a function pointer as opposed to a function which returns a pointer.

Comment: @KerrekSB Neither.  There is no context where arrays of references are permitted.  As a function parameter, of course, and array of `T` is converted to a pointer to `T`, but you can't have pointers to a reference either.  The first is excellent as an example as to how to read C++ declarations, but you really do need to point out that it isn't legal C++.

Comment: @JamesKanze: But a function taking a reference-to-array is exactly what the OP has, and it's a common (templated) function signature: `void foo(char (&arr)[N])`... how is that in error? I'll add that you cannot have free-standing declarations if you like, though.

Comment: @KerrekSB That's not an error.  But that's not your first example, either.  There's no problem with references to arrays (or references to pointers); what's illegal is an array of references (or a pointer to a reference).

Comment: Wow, 4 up-votes while the comments point out 2 errors and the rest is repeating the question.

Comment: Ahh, I'm very sorry, I was being thick. You're (all) right, I misunderstood -- I'll edit it now!

Answer (score 0):

`c++decl` mostly works for this.  It's just a bit picky about what you give it.

```
c++decl> explain void foo(char (&)[5])
declare foo as function (reference to array 5 of char) returning void

c++decl> explain void foo(char &[5])
declare foo as function (array 5 of reference to char) returning void
```

As noted in another answer, an array of references is illegal.  The GNU C++ compiler reports:

> error: declaration of ‘x’ as array of references

By the way, [here](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+foo%28char+%28%26%29%5B5%5D%29) is a link to an online utility that serves `cdecl` (although it complains about references because the version hosted by the site is C-specific).